# Toggle a "paper-dialog" inside a "dom-repeat"

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, dom-repeat, paper-dialog

I have a "paper-dialog" object in a page. I can toggle it by a button if it is not inside a "dom-repeat" loop. But if I put it in a loop, "this.$.dialog.toggle();" will then referring to null.

```
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{news}}" index-as"index">
    <paper-dialog id="dialog"><h3>{{item.date}}</h3></paper-dialog>
    <paper-button on-tap="toggleDialog">View {{item.name}}</paper-button>
  </template>
```

and

```
  toggleDialog: function(e) {
      this.$.dialog.toggle();
    }
```

Any idea why "this.$.dialog" become null after placing the dialog in a loop?

Answer (score 2):

`this.$` won't work. You have to call `this.$$`  which is equal to `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector();`

plus, you have multiple elements with same ID which is absolutely against html standards.

So you can do something like:

```
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{news}}" index-as"index">
    <paper-dialog id="dialog" indexDialog$='[[index]]'><h3>{{item.date}}</h3>
    </paper-dialog>
      <paper-button on-tap="toggleDialog" index$='[[index]]'>View {{item.name}}
    </paper-button>
  </template>
```

and toggleDialog

```
  toggleDialog: function(e) {
      var index = e.target.getAttribute("index");
      this.$$('[indexDialog="'+index+'"]').toggle();
  }
```

you have to set some indetification (`index` attribute) , then in function you can get this attribute by calling `e.target.getAttribute` and the last step is to find `paper-dialog` with the same value inside `indexDialog` attribute by calling  `this.$$('[indexDialog="'+index+'"]')`

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution by adding an "array-selector", so "paper-dialog" outside the loop and is only having 1 instance. (and we feed different data into it).

```
<array-selector id="selector" items="{{news}}" selected="{{selected}}"></array-selector>
<paper-dialog id="dialog" entry-animation="scale-up-animation"
exit-animation="fade-out-animation">......
```

and with an assignment inside the toggle function

```
  toggleDialog: function(e) {
    var item = this.$.news.itemForElement(e.target);
    this.$.selector.select(item);
    this.$.dialog.toggle();
  },
```